# UITextview set Attribute Text cause Performance slow

Tags: ios, swift, text, attributes, uitextview

I'm beginner in iOS. I want to set UITextview Attribute text whenever user typing, That's ok but the problem is the performance is lag, and too slow. I don't know what happened. I would appreciate any of your help! thanks

```
  
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
       
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .left

        let alignTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.kern : 30,
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle,
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black,
         
            ]
        as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
       
        let atribute = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: alignTextAttributes)
        
        

       
        var cursorLocation = textView.selectedRange.location
        if text == ""{
            textView.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: atribute)
           cursorLocation -= 1
          
           
        }else{

            textView.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: atribute)
            cursorLocation += 1
        }
     
       textView.selectedRange.location = cursorLocation

       //add attachment image to another uitextview
        let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
        let imageNew = UIImage(named: "icon")
        attachment.image = imageNew

       let attString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
       txtViewAnother.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: attString)
 
        return false
                
      }
```

Comment: so sad no-one  help me

Comment: For start, looks like the var attributedString isn't used.

Comment: Farther more, consider storing alignTextAttributes as a class level property instead of recreating it each time the user types

Comment: Finally, try removing the last line in which the cursor location is changed and see if this is the cause for slow performance. If so, LMK and we will thing of a solution

Comment: Thanks so much @ArikSegal, set cursor location is the problem. So how can I set cursor location when typing as normal text?

Comment: One more thing, When I add attachment images in this method, the CPU grow as much as number of attachments added. I resize images but still happened.

Comment: Looks like you will need to post a different question about the CPU issue

Comment: @ArikSegal I have edited my question, add more code about attachment , pls check it.

Comment: Set the text attribute of the text view in `viewDidLoad`.  TextViewのattributeは`viewDidLoad`で設定してね。

Comment: @ElTomato I want to set it whenever user typing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing can be summarized as -

1. Add a paragraph style and other text attributes.
2. Read old value of `attributedText`, recreate a new instance of `NSAttributedString` with all of this data.
3. Manually manage cursor position (backward delete (-1) vs add a char (+1))
4. Manually update `textView.textStorage`.
5. `return false` - do not allow system to control typing.

There are A LOT OF OTHER DETAILS here which `UITextView` will automatically cover for you - if you allow system to control the typing. For example -

> You are not accounting for what happens when user selects a range of characters and hits backward delete. (-1 won't cover for this case).

Below code does exactly the same as your current code -

```
// Initialize once and reuse every time
lazy var paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle = {
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .left
    return paragraphStyle
}()

// Initialize once and reuse every time    
lazy var alignTextAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = {
    return [
        .kern : 30,
        .paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle,
        .foregroundColor : UIColor.black,
    ]
}()
    
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    // If I want to set each characters with different kern values, how can I do that?
    alignTextAttributes[.kern] = textView.text.count.isMultiple(of: 2) ? 30 : 10

    // This is the key part
    textView.typingAttributes = alignTextAttributes

    // Allow system to control typing
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Tarun. If I want to set each characters with different kern values, how can I do that?

Comment: You can change `.kern` value to your choice before assigning the `typingAttributes`. See the UPDATE.

Comment: thanks you , One more thing, When I add attachment images in this method, the CPU grow as much as number of attachments added, it lag . I resize images but still happened. I have edited my question by add more that code.  Please help me

Comment: For that, you can ask a new question that focuses on the Attachment part.

Comment: I'm worry about admin make it spam. it would be happy  if you can help me the attachment issue right now. But don't mind  I'll check your code and accept it soon. thanks you so much

Comment: I have added new question about that, please help me. Thanks

Comment: When I place cursor in front of first line, my textview has 1000+ words, the lag is begin occurs. Can you help me?

Comment: This is the least amount of code that you need to support dynamic typing attributes. If you are still using this with a lot of attachments, the issues will show up eventually.

Comment: This problem occurs when I just only set attributes not attachment. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: No suggestion on this one. I guess the problem is when you have 1000+ words in the textView, and you enter a new character/word at the beginning, it has to update all other parts of the text inside the textStorage/textView UI representation. We are not causing any issue with our code. You can try to copy paste the same amount of text in Notes.app or any other app and will notice that the same lag happens there as well.

Comment: Thanks, reality you can paste 1 millions+ on note app but nothing lag happens.

Comment: Leave the Notes app alone, try it on a 3rd party app.

Comment: I have tried on another apps. They works very well

Comment: Can you try removing the `.kern` part from the attributes for testing and see if this is causing the issue?

Comment: yes `.kern.` cause problem. but I need to change width of each characters. any suggestion?

Comment: I know it sounds stupid, but maybe adding a fixed number of spaces (4, 6 or 8 depending on your font size) will give you a similar look. You have to manage insertion/deletion automatically for these additional spaces so that user don't have to delete them with additional backward delete key hits. Please consider asking a new question that focuses on this part and note in there that `.kern` creates issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the last line in which the cursor location is changed and see if this is the cause for slow performance. If so, try executing this part after a small delay:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(5)) {[weak self] in
        self?.myTextView.selectedRange.location += 1
    }
```