# How to optimize UITextView to stop lagging?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Recently, I’ve built a view controller with UITextView in it. The logic is simple, in viewDidLoad there is an API call to get lyrics from the db. The whole code that manages the setup of UITextView, can be found below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        Track(id: track!.id).getLyrics { [self] response in
            guard let text = response?.lyrics_text else { return }
            
            var writtenBy = response?.lyrics_writers ?? ""
            
            if writtenBy.isEmpty {
                writtenBy = track?.album?.artistsString() ?? ""
            }
            
            let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            style.lineSpacing = 10
            let attributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 19),
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(named: "Primary Material"),
                NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: style
            ]
            
            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: writtenByPhrase+" "+writtenBy+"\n\n"+text, attributes: attributes as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any])
            
            attributedText.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 19) as Any, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: writtenByPhrase.count))
            
            textView?.attributedText = attributedText
            
            textView?.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 20
            textView?.textContainerInset.top = 20
            textView?.textContainerInset.bottom = 200
            
            textView?.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location: 0, length: 0))
        }
}
```

When I test it on a real device and scroll through the content, it lags for the first time as it preloads to the memory, I suppose. However, when you’ve scrolled through all the content already, the scrolling starts to be smooth.

How to manage to remove lags on the first time of the scrolling?

Comment: Check out this repsonse - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67983921/uitextview-set-attribute-text-cause-performance-slow